# Understand if my proof is fallacious.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

I would like to know if my attempted solution to problem 4 of chapter 3.5 from Velleman's book *How to Prove It* is valid. My solution is different from the one suggested by the book and I want to know if my reasoning is fallacious to avoid repeating it in the future, if that is the case.

**The problem is as follows:**

Suppose  $A\cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$. Prove that $A\subseteq B$.

**This is my proof attempt:**

Suppose $A\cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ and $A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$. Let $x$ be arbitrary and suppose $x \in A$. Since $x \in A$ it follows that $x \in A \cup C$. But we know that $ A \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$, so $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. We will consider these cases separately.

1. Case $x \in B$: then no further reasoning is needed.
2. Case $x \in C$: then $x \in A \cap C$, so since $A\cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ it follows that $x \in B$

Thus $x \in B$. Since $x$ was an arbitrary member of $A$ we can conclude that $A \subseteq B$. $\blacksquare$

**And this is the book's solution:**

Suppose $x \in A$. We now consider two cases:

1. Case $x\in C$. Then $x \in A \cap C$, so since $A\cap B \subseteq B \cap C$, $x \in B \cap C$ and therefore $x \in B$.
2. Case $x \notin C$. Since $x \in A$, $x \in A \cup C$, so since $A\cap B \subseteq B \cap C$, $x \in B \cup C$. But $x \notin C$, so we must have $x \in B$.

Thus, $x \in B$, and since $x$ was arbitrary, $A \subseteq B$. $\blacksquare$

So, the book's proof uses a division into cases that are not suggested by any of the assumptions and that I did not think of. Is there any problem with my proof?

Comment: Your proof works just fine!

Comment: You have a typo in your case $2$.  I think you want to say $A \cap C \subseteq B \cap C$.  Other than that your proof is good.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What if $A=C=\{1\}$ and $B=\varnothing$?

Comment: Robert Shore seems to be correct about the typo. The claim that you're trying to prove, as written, is wrong, but you can correct it by writing $A\cap C\subseteq B\cap C$ instead of the first inclusion. Each case $2$ needs to be rewritten also. With those corrections, your proof is correct. It's also not much different from the book's proof. The work you do before the cases is part of the book proof's case $2$.

Comment: Indeed there was a typo, how embarrasing. The correct proposition is $A  \cap C \subseteq B \cap C$ and I have already corrected it. Thank you all for your answers. Now just to get a deeper understanding of proofs involving disjunctions, what could have been the thought process behind the decision of the author to select the cases $x\in C$ and $x\notin C$?. I would like to be able to distinguish the situations where it is advantageous to use the law of excluded middle, as the book suggests.

Comment: There is frequently more than one way to write a proof.  I would have tried proof by contradiction.  Suppose A is not a subset of B.  There is an x in A that is not in B.  This will eventually lead to a contradiction.